# Apache how to create default host for https

Tags: virtualhost, apache-2.4, http, redirect, https

I have several sites on my server. For example: domain1.com and domain2.com.
If user requests a not existing sub-domain (For example: a.domain2.com) he will be redirected to domain1.com. I want to show 404 page if this situation happens. For http traffic I use such config for vhost:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:80>
    Redirect 404 /
    ErrorDocument 404 "Page Not Found"
</VirtualHost>
```

I also have https versions of my sites. I have tried to do something like this:

```
<VirtualHost _default_:433>
    Redirect 404 /
    ErrorDocument 404 "Page Not Found"
</VirtualHost>
```

But my https sites stop opening. How to achive http behavior for https?

Comment: What error do you get when trying HTTPS?

Comment: Chrome says that your connection is not private.

Comment: Rereading through your post, can you clarify: You have the several web sites working fine... but when you put this entry in your config file, all the HTTPS sites stop working. Is that correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess right now is one of two things:

- You do not have an SSL certificate specified for the HTTPS virtual host
- Your certificate is for domain1.com, but is not a wild card certificate and/or does not have a Subject Alternative Name for a.domain1.com configured.

If you want HTTPS to work for a.domain1.com and b.domain1.com and whatever.domain1.com, your best option is to get a wildcard certificate for *.domain1.com

Comment: I have correctly configured named vhosts for my https versions of sites. But when I'm trying to add default vhost for *:443 apache starts ignoring my named vhosts. Crome start saying that your connection is not private and doesn't show anything but error page. I have tried to use "SSLEngine on" but than I should configure correct ssl certificates. I don't know what ssl certificate to use. I want common solution for many domains.

Comment: Chrome will usually include in the error... something like "NET::ERR_CERT_COMMON_NAME_INVALID". Do you see anything like that? What does it say?